# Is discussing coding style under questions constructive?

Tags: discussion, comments, declined-flags

Under my question an user started the good old war on whether we should write `int* name` or `int *name`.

> Sidenote: the `*` for pointers belongs to the name, not the type. Trick question: "`int* p, q;`: what types are `p` and `q` and why?" So better write `int *p, q;` consistently.

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2660648/607407) sums this issue nicely:

> It doesn't matter. Someone will now come along and close the question
> as a dupe, and someone else will show how the `int* a` way breaks if you
> declare multiple variables in the same declarations while the `int *a`
> way better reflects the syntactical structure of the code, and another
> guy will show that Stroustrup prefers the `int* a` way.
>
> Many opinions, but no "right" way here.

That's also what I linked in reply to the comment. The person then went into full rant<sup>maybe civilized, yes, but still just pressing same claim with more words</sup> mode.

> @TomášZato: And you can write a whole C program in one line. Which is
> the same argument as your's. Reason why we format code properly and
> even use comments from time to time (at least those who prefer to
> still understand the code one year later) is: readability and
> maintenability. If you read the C grammar, you might nottice the `*` is
> part of the declarator, not the type-specifier. It only does not
> matter for a single declarator for obvious reasons. So why not be
> consistent? (btw. I know of three coding styles which require that and
> none for the other).

I just replied that I am flagging that comment as non-constructive and focused on solving the actual problem in my question.

Later I found out that my flag was declined, my reply deleted and the irrelevant rant is still there. It's noteworthy that someone else has commented that this particular user does this often - that comment was deleted too.

Is discussing irrelevant aspects in comments no longer something that belongs in chat? I've seen many discussions about coding style deleted by a moderator, has something changed? (I even suggested that the comment author starts a chat and we'll talk about it)

I'd like the moderators to explain what is constructive about that comment so that I feel no incentive to flag comments like this any more.

Of course, you can see the full question here: [Forward define struct AND type without any warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41559799/607407)

As you can see it is not question about syntax of pointers or coding style in general. It's nice to point out possible error you see in someone's question, but if the person acknowledges your warning, further ranting/explaining/arguing is in my opinion not constructive.

I looked up what we have in our [help section on comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), and it backs my experience with StackOverflow up to this day:

> ##When shouldn't I comment?
>
> - ...
> - **Secondary discussion** or debating a controversial point; please use [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) instead;

Comment: i mean, that comment is more relevant than the one saying it isn't constructive at least.

Comment: Someone expressing a viewpoint that you disagree with doesn't make their argument a "rant".  It's an entirely constructive statement with an appropriate tone and that's making on topic arguments.  You may disagree with their position, or think that they're wrong, but that doesn't make the comment unconstructive.

Comment: @KevinB Well, when flagging, I expected ALL the comments related to the pointer syntax war to be deleted, including mine. Instead, moderator clearly visited the discussion and left the flame in. Almost sounds like an invitation to continue with the flame.

Comment: @Servy The first comment was constructive. To continue ranting when I'm clearly already aware of the issue is nonsense. And if not, then apparently I can reply to that rant with another rant. Doesn't sound like what comments are for.

Comment: @TomášZato Telling you things that you already know doesn't make them a rant, nor does it make them "not constructive".  It makes them not useful to you, sure.  That's very different.  "I don't want to hear this" is not in fact a valid reason for deleting someone else's comment, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Servy \*searching questions with coding style I disagree with and commenting on them\*

Comment: Strangly, i higly agree with the comment brought up by this post

Comment: @AntoinePelletier That's ok. But this isn't about how many people agree with which style. This is that discussions about coding style belong in chat. If you see someone using weird style, you tell them and move on. If you keep pushing it, that's IMO off topic and belongs in chat.

Comment: Yes it's off topic, but bringing the person into a private chat just to tell him : hey, that syntax should be (whatever) other syntax... Should a question unsing strange syntax be edited to a more normal syntax ? such as bad english being sometimes edited to good english ? not that i'm the syntax master. but...

Comment: I think you're missing the fact that he posted a comment about my syntax and then **second** comment about the same thing.  already said that I see nothing wrong about commenting on code in question. But turning that into a debate and arguing some points is not what comments are for. And it doesn't matter how right you are and how civil and polite your arguments are. They are still argments.

Comment: @Servy Your first comment here probably deserves further reply: you yourself are using word *arguments*. Comments are not for arguments. Viewpoint was noted, further argumenting is not for comment section.

Comment: @TomášZato Comments are a place where, among other options, it's appropriate to add additional information that the author might find useful, in this case, the suggestion on how to improve the quality of your code, a suggestion to which the author provided an argument to support their position.  That's entirely appropriate.  There's a *huge* difference between an argument that you present to support your position and having an argument with someone else.  In the former context "argument" is simply "evidence supporting your position".

Comment: @Servy Yeah, and we could pile up evidence for our positions till' the comment section explodes. Been there, done that. The reason why this didn't happen today was only because I refused to bring up my arguments and instead followed what I think is correct - marked the comment and went by my business.

Comment: @TomášZato Linking to your arguments instead of stating them isn't meaningfully different.  You presented your opposing views, and so the other person responded to your stated opposing view by explaining why they felt that your opinion wasn't appropriate.  If you actually didn't care at all, all you had to do was not respond, rather than responding with why you disagree with their position, particularly if you planned on being offended if the other user reacts to your stated position.

Comment: So basically the conclusion is: If someone comments on well-known controversial aspect of my post (be it pointers, extending prototypes or something political), instead of replying there, I can go find some of their posts manifesting opposite stance (eg. using opposite pointer syntax) and comment on there that I'd recommend changing that style.

Answer (score 9):

Comments are not for extended discussion, so if this subject is on-topic on SO,  feel free to ask a separate question. Coding style questions are not on-topic as they are strictly opinion based (except a couple well known cases already answered like the placement of curly braces in JavaScript next to a return statement). So avoid discussing it in the comments, and don't try to ask it as a separate question.

What should have been your initial reaction to the code style comment was to  mentally acknowledge it and move on. Instead you decided to dig out a link to some random opinion and present it as absolute proof of your point of view. As expected, it led to more comments. A plausible action at that point is to mark all but the first comment about style as "too chatty" (including your own) or flag "other: remove all code style discussion from comments" and move on.

Note: commenting "I am flagging that" is not constructive and can easily be construed as offensive. Avoid adding such comments (unless you are guiding some other person on how flagging works. Even then, linking to a Meta post would be better).

Comment: _"you should have mentally acknowledge it and move on. Instead you decided to dig out link to some random opinion and present it as absolute proof of your point of view."_ - +1. In this case, the OP start the "good old war" not the commenter. The correct action was to (a) ignore the comment (b) use the comments advice. There was no need to invoke further discussion on an already touchy topic.

Comment: The post I linked doesn't prove anything. And when I flaged the reply as non constructive, I indeed expected my replies to be deleted too. At least that's how it always worked in the past.

Comment: @TomášZato there is often significant difference on how one *expects* their post/comment to be viewed and how it is *actually perceived*. The comment "I think this answer wraps the whole issue nicely" is very likely read by many people (me included) closer to "my way is the way and you just know nothing" than neutral comment you possibly wanted to write.